# What transaction specific parameters can be set at the database level for Microsoft SQL Server to fix deadlock issue?

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, sql-server-2016, database-deadlocks

I have a JPA application that runs just fine on Oracle and MySql. However, on Microsoft SQL Server 2016, I have several known places where I am getting dead lock conditions.

I have been working on point solutions to resolve this issues but two things occur to me: one, this application is working in other database environments.  Two, there are likely other places in the application I don't know of that will display the same deadlocking behavior.

I am seeing lots of indications that there are parameters that are configurable but not at the database or system level (e.g. ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS/ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS).

I have found the following database parameters and I have tried setting the following:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydb
SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON;

ALTER DATABASE mydb
SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
```

But when I execute the following queries they both return null so I'm not sure the set queries worked (although they both return "Command(s) completed successfully.").

```
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('mydb', 'ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION');
SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('mydb', 'READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT');
```

After setting these parameters I still get the deadlocks.

Have I correctly set the above database parameters?

Are there other database or system scoped parameters I can set so the transaction isolation level allows for the same transactions that are accepted by MySql or Oracle?

Comment: [`DATABASEPROPERTYEX`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/databasepropertyex-transact-sql) has very nice documentation, and clearly lists that those are *not* properties. The settings you're looking for are recorded in [`sys.databases`](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/ms178534) (`snapshot_isolation_state_desc` and `is_read_committed_snapshot_on`, respectively).

Comment: Deadlocks in SQL Server are often caused by a need for query and index tuning so I suggest you review that before database settings. A common gotcha is using Unicode strings/parameters against varchar columns, which results in non-sargable expressions.

Comment: Even with both those options on, all it does is make the `READ COMMITTED` isolation level (the default) use snapshot isolation. If your code uses explicit transactions, it can still use another isolation level (like `SERIALIZABLE`), which is still subject to locking. There is no silver bullet to fixing deadlocks -- the actual bullet is investigating what they are, and you'll have to bite it. MySQL and Oracle may have different locking policies that lead to less deadlocks, but they still do lock. Deadlocks are often a sign of inefficient queries holding locks for too long.

Comment: This is similar in tone and content to other postings I've been reading regarding locking and transaction management in Sql Server.  This makes Microsoft Sql Server a really unattractive option for our application.  There must be away to make it easier.  Sell me.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything easier. If snapshot isolation doesn't do it for you, and you're not interested in diagnosing the deadlocks, your best bet probably *is* not to support SQL Server. Nobody's forcing you to use it, unless they are, in which case that's your motivation. There is no magic `DO_NOT_EVER_DEADLOCK` option, which seems to be what you're looking for. (In-memory OLTP, introduced in 2014 and perfected in 2016, truly uses no locks at all, but while attractive, that's not a universal solution either as not everything always fits in memory.)

Comment: Thanks for the input Jeroen.  I'm not exactly looking for a DO_NOT_EVER_DEADLOCK option.  More along the lines of "mysql/oracle have global settings that allow this transaction to execute, I'd like to be able to configure Sql Server to allow the same types of transactions".  And by "configure Sql Server to allow the same types of transactions" I kind of mean: I'd like to set Sql Server to be as liberal as possible with its locking strategy.

Comment: To prevent deadlocks, "liberal" is actually the opposite of what you want. If every transaction took a table lock, by definition, there'd be no problems with deadlocks since transactions couldn't hold competing lock sets. (Of course, this would have a hugely negative effect on performance.) The major problem in SQL Server is the fact that the optimizer has no way to design locking strategies across queries that will prevent or at least minimize deadlocks. It can and will produce plans that "naturally" cause deadlocks by taking locks in opposing order. There's no global option to fix that.

Comment: How was the database scripted in SQL Server? Do all of the tables have a PK w clustered index, or are they all heaps?